# Unable to install Caffe on windows

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, caffe, matcaffe

I am trying to install Caffe deep learning platform on windows and struggling for many days. Unfortunately, I am still unsuccessful in installing it.

I followed the instructions that Neil has mentioned on [his blog](https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/opencv-2-4-9-cuda-6-5-visual-studio-2013/). During setting Cmake in step 3, I could not find ‘CMAKE_LINKER’ to check it, I ignored this one and tried to build "ALL_BUILD" in "OpenCV.sln" file in visual studio 2013. I am getting errors with the title **error LNK**.

- Does anybody know about this CMAKE_LINKER that how should I bring it
  on the CMake list to configure?
- Which software/library should I include?
- Could you please guide me how to install Caffe?I will be thankful if
  you have any step by step tutorial, share with me.

your help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Windows branch](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows), it installs well.
Checked on vs2015 on Win10 x64 OS.